# Limiting RAM and CPU cores

Tags: boot, cpu, bios

I want to limit the number of CPU cores and RAM which the OS sees. Is there any way of doing this in BIOS ? I tried changing the grub file with maxcpu parameter. Is there something which I can do in the BIOS itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for testing purposes, then I would virtualise the environment.  That way you have complete control over the amount of CPUs and RAM the VM sees (even above your physical limits).

Answer (score 0):

There's no value add in limiting cores in the BIOS, so few BIOS manufacturers do so. Stick to handling it at the OS level.

Comment: The problem is the image which I am trying to boot works only on a single processor machine. That is the reason I want to disable the other CPU cores.